# Use PHP $_GET[ for displaying different content in the same PHP file - is there another way to do it?

Tags: php, url, parameters

Normally I use $_GET to catch the URL parameters and display content dependend on what the parameter is.

```
<?php

function isCmd($cmd) {
    if(isset($_GET["cmd"]))
        if($_GET["cmd"] == $cmd)
            return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

if(isCmd("page1")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 1</p>";
}
else if(isCmd("page2")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 2</p>";
}
else if(isCmd("page3")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 3</p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>That is the normal page</p>";
}
```

The url would look like these
example.com/script.php
example.com/script.php?**cmd=page1**
example.com/script.php?**cmd=page2**
example.com/script.php?**cmd=page3**

And it works as expected, but I see on websites they can do just:
example.com/script.php?**page1**
example.com/script.php?**page2**
example.com/script.php?**page3**
and it would work, without *cmd=*

How can I do the same in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` which will return the string after the "?" in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I answered it myself after looking into the $_GET supervariable. It was easier than I thought.

```
function isCmd($cmd) {
    if(isset($_GET["$cmd"]))
            return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

if(isCmd("page1")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 1</p>";
}
else if(isCmd("page2")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 2</p>";
}
else if(isCmd("page3")) {
    echo "<p>That is page 3</p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>That is the standard page</p>";
}
```

Also works with $_GET.
It would work with $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] too.

Comment: Your code should be `isset($_GET[$cmd])` note there's no quotes around the `$var`

Comment: Might be true, but $_GET["$cmd"] does work too and it has a reason why I put it in quotes. To see that I want to access a $_GET attribute by a dynamic/changing/not hardcoded index.